# How to open java jfr file directly with Windows open with?

Tags: java, jdk

By associating `*.jfr` file to open with `jmc.exe` version 8.2.0 does not directly work in Windows 10. `jmc.exe` opens but not the with clicked `jfr` file. How to make one click open to work with jfr?

Answer (score 3):

Go to register:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\jmc.exe\shell\open\command
Edit the value to include '-open' like so:
"C:\JAVA_RUNTIMES\JMC820\jmc.exe" -open "%1"